# Java - Does HttpsURLConnection works in Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, frontend, backend, urlconnection

I have a problem with my Java code in a Docker container scenario.
I have to open a connection with HttpURLConnection method, but response is a **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.**
I call this container from another frontend container that runs in localhost:3000.
In local works very well (with frontend container and running backend locally) and I don't know why there is this issue when I also use backend in container. I also tried with google url, but with same result.
For simplicity, I show you my code:

public boolean readResponseHeaders() {

```
boolean enq = false;
try {
  URL obj = new URL("https://www.google.com");
  HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)obj.openConnection();

  logger.info("conn: "+conn.getContentType());

  Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();

  System.out.println("Printing Response Header...\n");


  for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey()
      + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

return enq;
```

}

"conn" returns null value and obviously there is no key/value printed from for loop, instead in local backend "conn" returns "text/html" and key/value are valued.

Comment: What is the command you used to start the container? 
Did you do port mapping?

Comment: I start container with docker-compose up (I'm using docker-compose.yml file, with exposed ports --> ports: - 8080:8080)

Comment: Check if the port 8080 if there is any process listening. You can use netstat-ona command in unix

Comment: Yes, my backend container is listening on 8080.

Comment: Things I would to do are: 1) call my backend from frontend (localhost:3000 in browser) ----- 2) in backend use openConnection() method with URL obj = new URL("https://localhost:3000"); to get response headers of my frontend

Comment: UPDATE: now I can open connection with google url, but error with my localhost:3000 persists.

Comment: curl google in your container first to make sure your network is fine @crazyfrog